# Bootstrap tooltip function is called asynchronously. How to wait for it to finish before calling next function?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, async-await, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

In my below Function I want to ensure that first `tooltip("destroy")` finishes, and then my next line `takeScreenshot()` get executed. Unfortunately Bootstrap official documentation states that `tooltip("destroy")` is an Asynchronous function, therefore in below code, `takeScreenshot()` is executed, even before tooltip is destroyed.

Currently I have tried 2 approaches:

Approach 1: Use Async - Await: This didn't solve the problem.

Approach 2: Use setTimeout to delay execution of `takeScreenshot()`. This solved the problem but it seems to be hack rather than a standard solution.

Is there a way in Javascript or Jquery that I can solve this problem?

Below is my code that doesn't work synchronously :(

```
const processScreenshot = () => {
  $('#draggableDiv').tooltip("destroy"); // this line is asynchronous in nature
  takeScreenshot()  // this line gets executed 1st before previous line returns
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `.tooltip` doesn't accept a callback argument? Many `jQuery` functions DO accept callback arguments, so it wouldn't be surprising to find out `.tooltip` does as well.  It _does_ appear `tooltip` offers some events that maybe you could bind to?  Do you need to wait until it's destroyed, or do you just want it hidden? If so, maybe [hidden.bs.tooltip](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/) will get you what you need.

Comment: You are right. ''hidden.bs.tooltip'' solved it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you mention "destroy" instead of dispose (Bootstrap 4 uses dispose in favor of destroy), I think you're using a Bootstrap 3.x. With that assumption, you should be able to listen for 'hidden.bs.tooltip' like so:

```
$('#myTooltip').on('hidden.bs.tooltip', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips and confirmation of intended behavior / merge request resolving issue where this was broken: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13031

This would let you be sure that the tooltip has at least been hidden. I don't see any events for actually being destroyed.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer solved my problem. And yes this is Bootstrap 3 I am using in my code. tooltip("destroy") function also triggers the 'hidden.bs.tooltip' event and that solved my issue.